# How to quantify and sum up the effect of each record of two time series on their correlation?

Tags: time-series, correlation, python, r-squared

Let's say I have two one-day time series data. Each has 24 points (24 hours).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.array([datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, i, 0) for i in range(24)])
y1 = np.random.randint(100, size=x.shape)
y2 = np.random.randint(100, size=x.shape)

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I can calculate the coefficient of determination (R<sup>2</sup>) and the value will change when I remove a point.

How can I quantify the effect of each point (hour) on the R<sup>2</sup>? I want to quantify the effect of each point and then sum the quantified criteria of a subset of points so that I can compare the effect of different subsets on the R<sup>2</sup>.

For example, an ideal metric that I am looking for enables me to attribute the R<sup>2</sup> of the two time series (y1 and y2) to each time step (e.g. 18:00 contributes 20% and 15:00 contributes 15% of the R<sup>2</sup>). And the metric is also additive so that I can quantify the contribution of a subset of time steps (e.g. the contribution of 15:00 and 18:00 is 20+15=35%).

I would calculate R<sup>2</sup> with and without a point and use the difference as the effect of the point. However, this way of quantifying may not additive.

Comment: What is the idea of doing that? it sounds strange. It might be better to tell us what you want to obtain, what is your goal.  It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is `<X>`, and you're wondering
if `<Y>` is a good way to go about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As its written right now, 
the question appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your attention and sorry for the confusion. I couldn't get what the xy problem exactly is even after reading through the webpage. Instead, in my question, I added an example of one result that I want to have. I hope it makes things clearer and please let me point out what you can and cannot understand.